# Controlling access to files in Firebase Storage based on data in the Firestore database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-security

let's say I've got files in a folder in Firebase Storage and want to make specific files available only to specific users - and this mapping (users to files to which they should have access) is stored in a collection in the Firestore database.

There are generally too many users and files to either store user uids in the files' custom metadata fields or filenames in custom claims in user tokens.

Can I still implement such access control with Security rules somehow, or do I have to introduce a server just for this task?..

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible with Cloud Storage security rules to use data sources outside those you just mentioned (including Firestore).  This is a very common request.  If you would like to see this feature, please [file a feature request](http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features) to add your voice.

Until then, yes, you will have to introduce a backend.  Cloud Functions may work well for that, as long as your files are less than the maximum response payload of 10 MB.